# While applying dark mode in html/css/js through toggleList, I don't want one container to change the font color while switching to dark mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

In normal mode, background color is light-colored and page font color is black, and there is one of the sections where I don't want the font color to change when I toggle the background color to black and font color to white for the whole page when I switch to dark mode.

```
function Dark(){
    var element= document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("darkMode");
}
```

```
.darkMode{
    background-color: black;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to that section that you don´t want to change and in the css call it (The more specific attributes overlap with the general attributes).

Example:

```
<!--HTML FILE-->
<section class="selected"></section>


/*CSS FILE*/
.selected{color:/*some color*/;}
```

**Edit (A bit longer explanation):**

CSS uses a system called "Specifity" for setting properties between selectors, so every element gets a specific styling (and not multiple css declarations).
When you style the father of an element with certain CSS propertyes, the styles are given to the children as well. If we use the "Specifity" sistem, we can acceed to a higher styling prioryty level by calling the specific section with a class, so it´s styles will overwrite the father´s style.
I´m kinda new in stack so i´m sorry if my explanation isn´t good, please check [MDN web documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to get more (and better explained) information

Comment: Hey thanks, can you please explain your answer in a little more detail, I'm kinda new to coding.

Comment: I have just added an explanation. Sorry for the wait, I´ve just came back from holidays.