# Fit email template font color to light or dark mode

Tags: c#, html, css, templates, outlook

I have an issue when i send an email template, it only shows correct when user uses light mode, i share the images.
[image: Comparisson between dark mode(left) - light mode(right)]

Heres my fiddle→[Complete code here](https://jsfiddle.net/ENEAPPS/0v3Lt1j9/85/)
and my head code.↓

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

i tried using the meta tag,i tried setting color to specific elemts but, outlook always change the style. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution here, using classes outlook doesnt override the colors → https://stackoverflow.com/a/74815466/19087754